# How can I get BrowserBuild property in Browser Hawk

Tags: coldfusion, browser-detection

I am using Browser Hawk version (14.0.1.0) to detect browsers. But its showing IE 9 and IE 11 as IE 7 and IE 10 as NetScape version 5. I went through the forum of Browser Hawk where its written that for IE 9, IE 10 running in emulate IE 7 mode, the browser hawk will detect it as IE 7. So I need to check with the BrowserBuild property of browser. Please refer: https://www.cyscape.com/support/kb/XcIBViewItem.asp?id=951. Now I have written the code to get the BrowserBuild property. My code is

```
variables.bh = CreateObject("java", "com.cyscape.browserhawk.BrowserHawk");
variables.bi = bh.getBrowserInfo(getPageContext().getRequest());
variables.ebi = CreateObject("java","com.cyscape.browserhawk.ExtendedBrowserInfo");
variables.options = CreateObject("java","com.cyscape.browserhawk.ExtendedOptions");
variables.options.addProperties("BrowserBuild");
variables.req = getPageContext().getRequest();
variables.res = getPageContext().getResponse();
variables.ebi = variables.bh.getExtendedBrowserInfo(variables.req, variables.res, variables.options);
writeDump(variables.ebi.getBrowserBuild);
```

I am using ColdFusion server side language. Now its giving undefined value for BrowserBuild.

Again when I am dumping the browser build field like

```
WriteDump(variables.ebi.BROWSERBUILD);
```

Its giving 137438953472 for all browsers.

Any one please help how can I get the BrowserBuild property.

Comment: 1) The variable `variables.ebi` is created as a Java object then it is later destroyed without being used. That looks a little strange 2) can you include a screenshot of the `writedump()` ?